# Change color of the clicked button with ngClass, on buttons generated with ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a total of 80 buttons on screen that are rendered as follows:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let plans of PlanList">
    <td class="text-primary">{{plans.typename}} </td>
    <td class="text-center"><a (click)="criticalSelect(plans.typeid, '1', plans.plan1, '250')" class="btn btn-primary text-white">${{plans.plan1}}</a></td>
    <td class="text-center"><a (click)="criticalSelect(plans.typeid, '2', plans.plan2, '250')" class="btn btn-primary text-white">${{plans.plan2}}</a></td>
    <td class="text-center"><a (click)="criticalSelect(plans.typeid, '3', plans.plan3, '250')" class="btn btn-primary text-white">${{plans.plan3}}</a></td>
    <td class="text-center"><a (click)="criticalSelect(plans.typeid, '4', plans.plan4, '250')" class="btn btn-primary text-white">${{plans.plan4}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

When the button is clicked, I call criticalSelect()

It was all fine, until the user asked me to change the color of the clicked button from btn-primary to btn-success. I believe I have to do this with ngClass, but I do not know how to identify the button being clicked, and if another button is clicked, then place the previous button back to btn-primary and the new one to btn-success

Comment: Do you want to this happen to each row? I mean, 1st row one of buttons is btn-success and 2nd row one of buttons is also btn-success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider utilizing [ngForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) index exported variable to assign a predefined variable the last clicked button index, next use `ngClass` to conditionally apply `btn-success` to the element depending on whether its id equals to `lastClicked` as demonstrated below:

**Component:**

```
lastClicked: number;
```

**Template:**

```html
<tr *ngFor="let plans of PlanList; let index" (click)="lastClicked = index" [ngClass]="{'btn-success': index == lastClicked}" >
  <td class="text-primary">{{plans.typename}} </td>
  <td><a (click)="criticalSelect(...)" class="btn btn-primary text-white">${{plans.plan1}}</a></td>
  <td><a (click)="criticalSelect(...)" class="btn btn-primary text-white">${{plans.plan2}}</a></td>
  <td><a (click)="criticalSelect(...)" class="btn btn-primary text-white">${{plans.plan3}}</a></td>
  <td><a (click)="criticalSelect(...)" class="btn btn-primary text-white">${{plans.plan4}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi Rafi! It works, it changes the class for the button, but the entire row of buttons, not the one being clicked. I would send you a screenshot but I do not know how. Im trying to play with your code to find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks Rafi!

Comment: I modified it by adding a combination of the index and the values (money) of each field, to make every button unique. Thanks again.